# SchemDraw returns blank schematic when using logicparse

Tags: python-3.x, schemdraw

Python 3.8, Spyder IDE

I installed Schemdraw using,

`pip install schemdraw[matplotlib]`

I'm using the following code but all I get is a blank canvas,

```
import schemdraw
import schemdraw.elements as elm
from schemdraw import logic
from schemdraw.parsing import logicparse

with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
    logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$')
```

Also tried,

```
with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
    d = logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$')
    d.draw()
```

Gives a blank canvas.

Also tried,

```
with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
    d.add(logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$'))
```

Also tried,

```
d = logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$')
d.draw()
```

Returns nothing not even a blank canvas.

This throws the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Python codes\temp.py", line 10, in <module>
    d.add(logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$'))

  File "D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\schemdraw\schemdraw.py", line 233, in add
    element = element(**kwargs)

TypeError: 'Drawing' object is not callable
```

I have also tried (after the imports) just,

`logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$')`

which gives no output at all. I have the lastest version of `pyparse` installed.

Whereas the following simple circuit works fine,

```
with schemdraw.Drawing() as d:
    d.add(elm.Resistor())
    d.add(elm.Capacitor())
    d.add(elm.Diode())
```

Is there something obvious missing here?

Comment: Can you please show the full traceback for the "Drawing is not callable" error?

Comment: @mkrieger1 added full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
with logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$'):
    pass
```

logicparse returns a Drawing, so it doesn't work to put it inside a `with schemdraw.Drawing` block. But somehow Spyder's console doesn't seem to pick up the Figure from Drawing.draw().

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from schemdraw.parsing import logicparse

drawing = logicparse('not ((w and x) or (y and z))', outlabel='$\overline{Q}$')
drawing.draw()
```

Comment: I have tried that & it returns nothing, not even a blank canvas